# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. when importing ParseLoginUI as a module

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform, module

I'm new to Parse and I have some problem with the ParseLoginUI.

After importing ParseLoginUI as a module in my project, I clicked run app button, and the error happened. I've searched for solution on website for 2 days, but no one worked.

Below is my app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.parsetest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile project(':ParseLoginUI')
}
```

Below is the ParseLoginUI build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.1'

    provided 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
    provided files("$rootProject.projectDir/ParseLoginUI/libs/ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.10.1.jar")
    provided files("$rootProject.projectDir/ParseLoginUI/libs/ParseTwitterUtils-1.10.1.jar")

    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2'
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    androidTestCompile 'org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:1.2.3'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong? Because I followed the tutorial in this website: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android

But it still can not work.

---

Here is the error message.

> Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
>
> Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
>   WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20090211 is ignored for debugAndroidTest as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
>            In case of problem, please repackage with jarjar to change the class packages
>   :ParseLoginUI:compileLint
>   :ParseLoginUI:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
>   :ParseLoginUI:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :ParseLoginUI:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :ParseLoginUI:checkReleaseManifest
>   :ParseLoginUI:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :ParseLoginUI:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :ParseLoginUI:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :ParseLoginUI:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :ParseLoginUI:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42200Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :ParseLoginUI:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk401Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :ParseLoginUI:prepareReleaseDependencies
>   :ParseLoginUI:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :ParseLoginUI:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :ParseLoginUI:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :ParseLoginUI:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :ParseLoginUI:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :ParseLoginUI:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :ParseLoginUI:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :ParseLoginUI:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :ParseLoginUI:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :ParseLoginUI:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :ParseLoginUI:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :ParseLoginUI:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>   :ParseLoginUI:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
>   :ParseLoginUI:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
>   :ParseLoginUI:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
>   :ParseLoginUI:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
>   :ParseLoginUI:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
>   :ParseLoginUI:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
>   :ParseLoginUI:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
>   :ParseLoginUI:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :ParseLoginUI:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:checkDebugManifest
>   :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareParseTestParseLoginUIUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies
>   :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:dexDebug
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/parse/AbstractQueryController$1;","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)","sources":[{}]}
>
> FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 3.743 secs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'` conflicts with `'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'` and you have added 2 times `'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'`, so replace your dependencies with:

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], exclude: 'android-support-v4.jar',dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile project(':ParseLoginUI')
}
```

Comment: I've tried the solution you provided, but my app still can not work with the same error.