# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' when importing ParseUI-widget and Login as modules

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform, module, android-parsequeryadapter

I'm new to Parse and I have some problem with the ParseUI-Login and ParseUI-Widget.

After importing ParseLoginUI as a module in my project, I clicked run app button, and the error happened.

I have the exact same problem as Han ([Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. when importing ParseLoginUI as a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546446/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-when-importing-parseloginui-as)) however, the solution he was provided doesn't work for me..

I may also mention that I don't know what "clone the project" meant in the instructions, I downloaded the zip and imported the modules to android studio from "my downloads".

Below is my app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.joakim.parsetest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], exclude: 'android-support-v4.jar',dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile project(':ParseUI-Login')
    compile project(':ParseUI-Widget')
}
```

Below is the ParseUI-Login build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.1'

    provided 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
    provided files("$rootProject.projectDir/ParseUI-Login/libs/ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.10.1.jar")
    provided files("$rootProject.projectDir/ParseUI-Login/libs/ParseTwitterUtils-1.10.1.jar")
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }
}
```

and below is the ParseUI-widget build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.1'

    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2'
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    androidTestCompile 'org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:1.2.3'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your app build.gradle try this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], exclude: 'android-support-v4.jar',dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.4'
    compile 'com.parse:parseui-login-android:0.0.1' 
}
```

I had a similar problem for ParseUI-Login for my app and this worked for me.